# How to Access Media files using raw paths in Android R -- Android 11

Tags: android, mediastore, android-11

how can we Access Media files using raw paths in Android R -- Android 11

according to

https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage#media-files-raw-paths

it is said that `we can read a device's media files using direct file paths and native libraries`

`Mediacolumns DATA` is deprecated according to

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#DATA

Comment: What is a raw path?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage#media-files-raw-paths

Comment: Good question. There doesn't seem to be any additional information and the Feature Flag does not even seem to be available in the emulator as of today.

Comment: new android 11 developer preview release still no update on this issue https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage#media-files-raw-paths

Comment: So we don't need to migrate our apps from media file path usages to uri?

Comment: please refer this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151407044#comment10

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404

Answer (score 0):

The respective documentation available from Google is incomplete and only partially useful, especially it notoriously lacks examples. While trying to make my app Android 11 compatible I noticed this strange behaviour (using the *File* access method):

- A file named "/internal/bli/bla.db" exists, but is not readable.
- The file renamed to "bla.db.mp4" becomes readable.
- This also works with "bla.db.jpg".
- An audio file "whatever.mp4" in my music collection is readable.
- Any file named "folder.jpg" in my music collection is not readable.
- One of these files, duplicated as "mist.jpg", will become readable.
- The MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission removes all these limitations.

This first looked like a mess to me, but:

The reason why "folder.jpg" is not accessible may be that it is not included in the system's image database, because it has been identified as album cover image. On the other hand all files with file name extension ".mp4" or similar are listed in the respective audio media database and therefore are accessible.

This leads to my hypothesis: All files that are listed in Andorid's media databases (audio or image or movies or smells) can be accessed in read mode via their native file paths using the *File* method, maybe also for native (C or C++) programs. All other files, including images that were used for album covers, exist, but are not readable.