# Unable to access obb Directory on Android 11

Tags: android, file, android-11

I have a file Sharing app on the Play Store. The app can transfer selected apps and *.OBB* files associated with them. I am testing my app for android 11 but am unable to get obb files for apps even with *ALL_FILES_ACCESS*.

The android documentation states the following:-
*Write access to all internal storage directories⁠, except for /Android/data/, /sdcard/Android, and most subdirectories of /sdcard/Android. This write access includes file path access.*

*Apps that are granted this permission still cannot access the app-specific directories that belong to other apps because these directories appear as subdirectories of Android/data/ on a storage volume.*

So, in theory, I should have been able to read any file except for */Android/data* directory and write to any directory outside of */Android* directory except for */Android/media*.

Please correct me if I am wrong. If, access to obb is not possible this way, is there any other way or is my app's feature just ruined and user cannot transfer obb files at all?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app holds `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission it can access Android/obb directory.

Comment: is the link really necessary ?

Comment: @phoenixstudio Is there any problem with me providing the source of information?

Comment: yes since in `medium` he or she get paied for each time people read the article, people my consider it  span, which is any kind of promoting for paied services or to gain money

Comment: But it's a post from official Android Developers blog.

Comment: That said. I already had this permission in my app. And also provided it in android settings before asking the question. Is this a bug in my phone? (ROM mention:- I am testing on ElementalX Rom)

Comment: @Sakshamgupta Sorry, I can't check myself because I'm on Android 10.

Comment: @solru My app is working just fine. It was a bug in the custom ROM. Switching the ROM worked. I also tried with Oneplus with android 11.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a fix
In Play Store download Google Files.
If already installed.
Hold the app and goto app info,
In last allow both "modify system" And "install unknown app" and you can easily copy and move from and to obb and data folder from Google files.
Sorry for my bad English but I hope u can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable "install unknown apps" permission for any file manager app AFAIK, and you will have access. Worked on my Samsung device with Samsung my files app.