# Write files to the Android external storage using React Native FS

Tags: android, react-native, android-10.0, react-native-fs

My React Native Android application needs to save a JSON file in the special folder located in the external storage. I am trying to do it using RNFS (https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) this way:

```
const saveData = async () => {
    var path = `${RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/MyApp`;
    RNFS.mkdir(path);
    path += '/data.json';
    RNFS.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(getData()), 'utf8')
      .then((success) => {
        console.log('Success');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  }
```

It works well but fails on Android Q device. This error is shown:

`Error: Directory could not be created`

If I try to write a plain file without creating directory it throws this error:

`ENOENT: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory), open '/storage/emulated/0/data.json'`

However, I've added this permissions to my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And granted the external storage permissions in the settings. But if I change the `RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath` to `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath` it works without any errors. But I need to get an access to the external storage. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes on Android Q getExternalStorageDirectory() is not accessable anymore. You can read that here every day. Also how to use legacyExternalStorage in manifest to keep it working for Q. But better use a different directory to be ready for R.

Comment: `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath` Which path would that be?

Comment: @blackapps, it's `data/user/0/com.appName/files/`

Comment: /data/user/0/com.appName/files/ would be from getFilesDir(). The apps private directory. You do not need any permission then.

Comment: `But I need to get an access to the external storage.` Please explain why.

Comment: @blackapps, user has an abbility to create backups and restore them. Backup file must be available for user to edit, move or share it

Comment: Ok. You did not tell that the user would use a file manager or other app to do such. Or does your app provide that possibility?

Comment: @blackapps, yes, I tell user the location of the saved file, but it doesn't accessible becaues data folder requires a superuser rights. I want to make a special folder in the external storage, like in WhatsApp

Comment: You did not tell me if the user uses a file manager or an app others than yours to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out that legacy external storage access is required from Android API 29+. So, I've editied my `AndroidManifest.xml` (that located in `android/app/src/main/`) like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.appName">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
    ...
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    ...
    >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And everything has started to work. Also, I've added a request for granting permissions to the `saveData` function:

```
const saveData = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      ]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
    const readGranted = await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE); 
    const writeGranted = await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if(!readGranted || !writeGranted) {
      console.log('Read and write permissions have not been granted');
      return;
    }
    var path = `${RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/MyApp`;
    RNFS.mkdir(path);
    path += '/data.json';
    RNFS.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(getData()), 'utf8')
      .then((success) => {
        console.log('Success');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Ok. But this works for 29. Not for 30 as you suggested with 29+. This only gives you some time extra to solve your problem.

Comment: @blackapps, What should I do to make it work on API 30?

Comment: There will be another RNSF.ExternalFilesPath or something like that. Equivalent with getExternalFilesDir(). No permissions needed.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE : USE SCOPED STORAGE**

Alternatively, I found this library [react-native-file-access](https://github.com/alpha0010/react-native-file-access) which is use **Scoped Storage**. in my case, I stored the file in **Download** directory.

First, with RNSF we need to download the file and set the destination at `RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath`, then copy the downloaded file with [react-native-file-access](https://github.com/alpha0010/react-native-file-access) to specific folder (Download in my case).

```
FileSystem.cpExternal(localFileUrl, `${filenameFormatted}`,'downloads')
```

maybe you can use this library to store file in your specific directory with some adjustment

**USE PERMISSION MANAGE EXTERNAL STORAGE (NOT RECOMMENDED) :**

In Android 11 and above, the permission for accessing storage has changed. you have to add additional permission called **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**, see these post :

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#directory-access
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

add this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

i create simple permisson request based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/10851423) call this native function from react native.

create **PermissionFileModule.java** in `app/src/main/<your_package>`

```
public class PermissionFileModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {

    public PermissionFileModule(@Nullable ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        reactContext.addActivityEventListener(this);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "PermissionFile";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void checkAndGrantPermission(Callback errorCallback, Callback successCallback) {
        try {
            if (!checkPermission()) {
                requestPermission();
                successCallback.invoke(false);
            } else {
                successCallback.invoke(true);
            }
        } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
            errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
        } else {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getReactApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getReactApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s",getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                getCurrentActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                getCurrentActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
            }
        } else {
            //below android 11
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getCurrentActivity(), new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 2296) {
            if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "Access granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "Access not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

create **PermissionFilePackage.java** in `app/src/main/<your_package>`

```
public class PermissionFilePackage implements ReactPackage {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new PermissionFileModule(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

in **MainApplication.java**, add **PermissionFilePackage.java** as additional package

```
...
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
@SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
    List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
    // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
    // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
    packages.add(new PermissionFilePackage());
    return packages;
}
...
```

in your RN Component, call the permission file like this

```
...
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
var PermissionFile = NativeModules.PermissionFile;
...

if (Platform.Version >= 30) {
        PermissionFile.checkAndGrantPermission(
          (err) => {
            DeviceUtils.showAlert(
              'Sorry',
              'Access not granted',
            );
          },
          (res) => {
            if (res) {
              checkDirectoryAndDownload(url, name, ext);
            }
          },
        );
      } else {
        DeviceUtils.grantPermissionSingleAndroid(
          PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
          (isAllow) => {
            if (isAllow) {
              checkDirectoryAndDownload(url, name, ext);
            } else {
              DeviceUtils.showAlert(
                'Sorry',
                'Access not granted',
              );
            }
          },
        );
      }
```

Comment: where is code for DeviceUtils?

Comment: it's just helper class for showing alert, you can replace it with something that have similar purpose

Answer (score 2):

With Android version 10 (API level 29) the concept of scoped storage is introduced.
According to Docs-

> "To give users more control over their files and to limit file
> clutter, apps that target Android 10 (API level 29) and higher are
> given scoped access into external storage, or scoped storage, by
> default. Such apps have access only to the app-specific directory on
> external storage, as well as specific types of media that the app has
> created."

For Android version 10, you have the option to opt-out of scoped storage by
adding
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the AndroidManifest.xml like this->

```
<application ...
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
...>
....
</application>
```

This is a temporary solution and will work only for android version 10 and not above it.
Also make sure you ask run-time permission for read/write external storage.

Answer (score 1):

The following path should results in the file "banana" being in the folder **Internal storage > Download** on the phone, assuming the above mentioned write permissions are in place:

```
const path = RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath/Download/banana;
```

You must append "/Download" to the path. Files can then be found in "Internal storage > Download".

Note: Initially I was trying to create a file in the top-level **RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath** but that failed to show up on the phone for the user. Appending the /Download fixes it and the file "banana" now exists in the folder "Internal storage > Download" on the phone.

Conclusion:

Without /Download it fails to create the file banana anywhere that I can see:

```
/storage/emulated/0/banana
```

With /Download it successfully creates the user-accessible file:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/banana
```