# How to access Android 11 another app /Android/data directory?

Tags: android, file, permissions, scoped-storage

My app is managing another application files, this other application was forced to move their files to the /storage/emulated/0/Android/data directory.

How can I access them?

All that I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887526/android-11-access-to-android-data-directory) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files) is that it's not possible but there are some file managers (X-plore, Total commander) that apparently can, so it might be somehow possible.

Comment: There exists no /Android/data directory to begin with. Please mention full path.

Comment: @Anthony you can check out my question here i have added code to access Android directory
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69831936/storage-access-framework-permission-denied-issue-even-when-permissions-granted

Comment: @User Thanks for the link! This week I've decided to go with FTP to read the files. This requires an FTP server that can access the files like Solid Explorer but at least the code is similar to the java.io.File to read files.