# Storage Access Framework- Permission denied issue even when permissions granted

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-file, android-11, scoped-storage

I am implementing Storage Access Framework to grant Android folder access. I have updated `targetSDKVersion=30` and on Android 11 i am having storage permissions issues. I want to get storage permission to access files inside `Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media`.

To make storage permissions work i have implemented Storage Access Framework to get `Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media` access and then fetch files inside its subfolders *(i.e .Statuses, WhatsAppImages)*

Below are code details

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />

 <application
        android:name=".application.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" // also tried removing this
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
```

**Activity Code**

```
   //First i checked and requested android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
) {
    //further work of opening directory
} else {

    TedPermission.with(this)
        .setPermissionListener(sdk30PermissionListener)
        .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
        .setPermissions(
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
        .check()
}

//This is the root path i want to hit to access all subfolders inside this one

public static final String whatsApp_root_path = "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media”;
companion object {
   const val ANDROID_DOCID = "primary:${Constants.whatsApp_root_path}"
    const val EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY =
        "com.android.externalstorage.documents"
    private val androidUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(
        EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, ANDROID_DOCID
    )
    val androidTreeUri = DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(
        EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, ANDROID_DOCID
    )
}

private val handleIntentActivityResult =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        if (it.resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return@registerForActivityResult
        val directoryUri = it.data?.data ?: return@registerForActivityResult
        contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
            directoryUri,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
        )
        if (checkIfGotAccess()) {
            premiumDialogHandling()
            onGotAccess()
        } else {
            Log.d("AppLog", "you didn't grant permission to the correct folder")
            tinyDB.putBoolean("SDK30Permissions", false)
            showWrongFolderSelection()
        }
    }
private fun checkIfGotAccess(): Boolean {
    return contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions.indexOfFirst { uriPermission ->
        uriPermission.uri.equals(androidTreeUri) && uriPermission.isReadPermission && uriPermission.isWritePermission
    } >= 0
}
private fun openDirectory() {
    if (checkIfGotAccess()) {
        onGotAccess()
    } else {
        val primaryStorageVolume =
            (getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager).primaryStorageVolume
        val intent = primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
            .putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, androidUri)
        handleIntentActivityResult.launch(intent)

    }
}


private fun onGotAccess() {
    tinyDB.putBoolean("SDK30Permissions", true)
//once user chooses ‘Use Folder’ to allow permissions
  processStatusFetchExecute()


}
public fun processStatusFetchExecute(completed: () -> Unit) {
    Timber.e("processStatusFetch:Init")

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
       var statusesFolder = File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            Constants.whatsApp_root_path
        ).listFiles(FileFilter { file -> file.name.equals("${Constants.FOLDER_NAME_STATUSES}") })

        val docIdStatuses = "${HomeActivity.ANDROID_DOCID}/${statusesFolder.get(0).name}"
        val childrenUriStatuses =
            DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(
                HomeActivity.androidTreeUri,
                docIdStatuses
            )

        val statusTreeUri = DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(
            HomeActivity.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, docIdStatuses
        )

        val hasAccess: Boolean =
            contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions.indexOfFirst { uriPermission ->
                uriPermission.uri.equals( HomeActivity.androidTreeUri) && uriPermission.isReadPermission && uriPermission.isWritePermission
            } >= 0
        
        Timber.e("processStatusFetch:Execute")
        val statusImages = arrayListOf<File>()
        val statusVideos = arrayListOf<File>()

        val png = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("png")
        val jpg = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("jpg")
        val jpeg = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("jpeg")

        val args = arrayOf(png, jpg, jpeg)
        val where = (MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
                + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
                + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?")
        var fileCursorExternal: Cursor? = null
        val orderBy = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED
        val column = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED
        )
        //Please note args,where, orderby are not working with contentResolver.query so i have handled file filter using loop

        val selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
        val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("jpg")
        val selectionArgsPdf = arrayOf(mimeType)
        fileCursorExternal = contentResolver.query(
            childrenUriStatuses!!,
            column,
            selectionMimeType,
            selectionArgsPdf,
            "date_modified DESC"
        )
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main + exceptionHandler) {

            async(Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler) {
                Timber.e("processStatusFetch:InProgress")
                while (fileCursorExternal!!.moveToNext()) {
                    val nameIndex =
                        fileCursorExternal.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)

                    val displayName = fileCursorExternal.getString(nameIndex)
                    val path =
                        "${Constants.whatsApp_root_path}/${Constants.FOLDER_NAME_STATUSES}/$displayName"
                    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")

                    if (getFileType(displayName) == FILETYPE.IMAGE) {
                        statusImages.add(
                            File(
                                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                path
                            )
                        )
                    } else if (getFileType(displayName) == FILETYPE.VIDEO) {
                        statusVideos.add(
                            File(
                                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                path
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }.await()
            Timber.e("processStatusFetch:Done")
            sharedViewModel.statusImages.postValue(statusImages)
            sharedViewModel.statusVideos.postValue(statusVideos)
            completed()
        }


    }
}
```

**What's done so far:**

*Using above code i have successfully displayed Media screen for use folder.*
[image]

*And i am also able to successfully fetch all the files inside `.Statuses` folder*

**Problem:**

When i set list of images to `Recyclerview` inside `RecyclerViewAdapter`. On setting file to `Imageview` i always getting `Permissions Denied` exception.

***Method 1: Tried setting file to image view using Glide***

```
Glide.with(itemView.context).load(file.absoluteFile)
    .listener(object :
        RequestListener<Drawable> {
        override fun onLoadFailed(
            e: GlideException?,
            model: Any?,
            target: Target<Drawable>?,
            isFirstResource: Boolean
        ): Boolean {
                        return false
        }

        override fun onResourceReady(
            resource: Drawable?,
            model: Any?,
            target: Target<Drawable>?,
            dataSource: DataSource?,
            isFirstResource: Boolean
        ): Boolean {
            val abc = "yes"

            return false
        }
    }
    ).into(imgview)
```

*Got below exception*

```
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There were 3 root causes:
java.io.FileNotFoundException(/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/6a8cb5d8dc8b4aba832c984c4f1e06c4.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))
java.io.FileNotFoundException(/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/6a8cb5d8dc8b4aba832c984c4f1e06c4.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))
java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

***Method 2: Tried setting file to image view using Uri***

```
imgview.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file))
```

*Got below exception*

```
resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/25340b4ddcf44eb2a8d6a5d0509feee9.jpg
W/ImageView: Unable to open content: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/6a8cb5d8dc8b4aba832c984c4f1e06c4.jpg
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/6a8cb5d8dc8b4aba832c984c4f1e06c4.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:115)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1498)
        at android.graphics.ImageDecoder$ContentResolverSource.createImageDecoder(ImageDecoder.java:286)
        at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeDrawableImpl(ImageDecoder.java:1758)
        at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(ImageDecoder.java:1751)
        at android.widget.ImageView.getDrawableFromUri(ImageView.java:1011)
        at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:980)
        at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:557)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageURI(AppCompatImageView.java:120)
        at mypkgname.StatusImageAdapterNew$ImageViewHolder.bindItems(StatusImageAdapterNew.kt:135)
        at mypkgname.StatusImageAdapterNew.onBindViewHolder(StatusImageAdapterNew.kt:81)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:561)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:625)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1775)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1263)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:797)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23242)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6513)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3152)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8601)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1035)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:858)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:789)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1020)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8051)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7923)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
        ... 85 more
    resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/6a8cb5d8dc8b4aba832c984c4f1e06c4.jpg
```

Reading both exceptions i can understand that the permissions i granted for Media folder inside Android may not be correct but it returns true when i check it.
Please note this is happening only on Android 11 because i updated SDK version to 30.

I am unable to resolve this issue i think i need to get bit more knowledge of Storage Access Framework to set these permissions correct because after that i need to work on writing/copying files.

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/6a8cb5d8dc8b4aba832c984c4f1e06c4.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
` You can never have that exception if you use SAF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Reading both exceptions i can understand that the permissions i granted for Media folder inside Android may not be correct

You cannot grant anything. Instead you were granted access to Whatsapp Media folder. But only while using SAF.

Now you have a bunch of irrelevant code where you define providers and paths. No good. Scary code.

And while you may succeed in listing all the files you are not using the uries of all those files (You should put them in an `<Uri>` list to be used by the recycle view) but with again all kind of tricks build up a File path.

So throw away all those provider and path definitions.

Just list the content of the Media folder with a direct query(). If you see the ".Statuses" folder listed then go and list that folder. And.. save the obtained file uries to an Uri list.

You started with SAF and converted to File. Dont do such nasty things. Your SAF permissions are no File permissions. You do not need any permission in manifest to use SAF.

Comment: Got it. I have implemented SAF somehow correctly following this blog post. 
https://medium.com/swlh/sample-for-android-storage-access-framework-aka-scoped-storage-for-basic-use-cases-3ee4fee404fc

Comment: And as you mentioned obtained a List of Uris , can use these uri's to display on imageviews but the issue is my entire working is with File objects, i cannot afford to change entire thing. I mean i cannot use Uris everywhere i need to convert this URI to file.

Comment: I tried using val fileObj=documentFile.uri.toFile but it throws an exception  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri lacks 'file' scheme: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses%2F0916765d27ae46b883ca7de728547c2f.jpg

Comment: The exception is very clear as its a SAF uri its not able to get file scheme. Is there any way to convert this SAF URI to java.io.File so that my entrie functionality keeps working as before with file objects. This includes downloading files to other folders, sharing files, deleting files , playing video files on player etc.

Comment: Or is there any way to convert DocumentFile to a normal File? How to move forward with this?

Comment: You should first tell why you think you need to convert saf uries to file system paths. Mostly one can do without as you could have seen here every week when people just ask this. Further i see no reason that you change all for `downloading files to other folders, sharing files, deleting files , playing video files on player ` too. Ask stackoverflow before you make conclusions. In a modern application one uses SAF, MediaStore and File

Comment: In a modern application one uses SAF, MediaStore and File. And even if you manage to convert a SAF uri to a File instance you have no access to this file using that File instance as you have seen. So give up..

Comment: Got it, not converting SAF Uri to a File, after user selects "Use Folder" on Android/Media, i have used MediaStore to fetch content from WhatsApp Images, .Statuses but the issue is CursorLoaded just always returns empty for hidden folder .Statuses and its working fine for WhatsApp Images

Comment: Why so? Its not working for Hidden folder, Can you share an example for fetching files using MediaStore on sdk 30?

Comment: Why wouldd you use mediastore? Use saf.

Comment: Any way to fetch all the properties of whatsapp statuses files like relative path, name, aspect ratio, duration(in case of video file) etc.