# How to Access Android/data folder in Android11 without using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android-11, data-storage

IS there anyone who can help in accessing other Application directory/folder Under Android/data/. I want to put some .bin files in other Application folder. Please help. As in Android11 due to some restrictions 3rd party apps are not allowed to access other folder.

Comment: Not to be rude, but why? This sounds like the reason why those restrictions have been put into place.

Comment: There are certainly reasons. For example, check https://support.copilotgps.com/en/support/solutions/articles/19000046269-how-do-i-import-custom-pois-on-android- where they suggest to put files in the application folder to add POIs to the navigation system. Some file managers can actually do that, so there is a way. The user explicitly needs to grant his or her permission.

Comment: See also this question with responses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887526/android-11-access-to-android-data-directory