# Effect of the update to Android 11 on persistable permissions already acquired

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, android-11

Scenario:

- An user has acquired the persistable permissions using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` with an App that targets latest Android API level 30 on Android 10 or previous to comply with storage access framework access permission policies.
- The folder chosen in the first point by the user is the main folder of internal storage or another folder that appears as greyed out when you try to take permissions with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` in Android 11 but can be chosen to get persistable permission in all previous versions.
- The user updates the OS version to Android 11.

Are the already obtained persistable permissions maintained or they will be invalidated after the update causing unexpected behavior?

Comment: I think that you certainly will loose permissions for the root(s) of external storage. What kind of unexpected behaviour do you fear? You can always check if a permission/obtained uri  is still valid before using one.

Comment: @blackapps I fear some unexpected kind of error when I try to get the access using the previous acquired persistable permissions

Comment: `You can always check if a permission/obtained uri is still valid before using one. `

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404