# Android 11 generate PDF, Excel file

Tags: android, itext

I am looking at scoped storage, SAF and so on in Android 11, but didn't find anything about how to create ItextPDF or JXL excel files. Usually we create new File object, with some path on device or external memory. But how to do that now in Android 11? I need it only to send it to printer or share.

```
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
...
```

Comment: "But how to do that now in Android 11?" -- the simplest solution is to create it in `getCacheDir()`, then copy it to the final destination.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404