# How save file in emulated/0 (android 11)

Tags: android, file

I have been reading the documentation of the new way of saving files in android 11 and it is not clear to me ...

How could I save a file in `/storage/emulated/0/`?

My code only works on android 9 or lower (android 10 if I use preserveLegacyExternalStorage property in manifest, but on android 11 it doesn't work)

Comment: Do you mean in `/storage/emulated/0` ?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404

Answer (score 1):

Android 11 introduces new approach to accessing storage, called [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). Now for storing in any path you need new permission for Android 11: `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (doc [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files), some rich FAQ aritcle in [HERE](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-11-storage-faq-78cefea52b7c))

This will allow you to get access to whole storage, all subfolders, not only folder dedicated for your app, but be aware that [not every app with this permission declared in manifest will be published in Google Play](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access-google-play). So you should respect new policy and keep your files only in [context.getExternalFilesDir("subdirName")](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), for reading some common types (images, videos, docs) you can still use [MediaStore API](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media)

Comment: just special apps will have granted this access, normal apps won't

Comment: yep, its under linked docs/faq - usual apps won't have access to whole storage, thats new system policy, it isn't created for bypassing