# How to obtain Request All files access on Android 11

Tags: android, android-storage, android-11

Im investigating the File access changes associated with Android 11

I've configured an AVD fro Android R and created a Test Application that has the following Manifest contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.my.application">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

I then create this Intent and start Activity expecting to see the Allow access to manage all files. in System Settings

```
    val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
    val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
    intent.data = uri
    startActivity(intent)
```

However the user is presented with the App Info screen for my test application.

If I search in settings I can find the `Apps & Notifications -> Special App Access -> All files access -> My test app is listed`

Is this the process users have to follow to grant this permission?

Why doesnt using the Intent I constructed take the User directly to the All Files Access page?

Comment: Please See this way in this link , It can be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67140033/12272687

Comment: Please See this way in this link , It can be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67140033/12272687
It can help to read/write access for all files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing an intent for

```
  Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
```

will give your app read/write access for all files even on removable micro sd card.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        //below android 11=======
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityPicture.class));
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
    }
```

Also add this to manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```