# How to Open Custom Gallery in Android 11

Tags: android, android-studio, scoped-storage

I am using a custom gallery to select the images but crashed in android 11 and i found due to scoped storage

Comment: add more details show your logcat so we can check

Comment: You'll have to describe what you tried, what happens specifically, and any relevant piece of code. Additionally, you might find this tutorial useful:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/10768834-scoped-storage-tutorial-for-android-11-deep-dive

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

> in Manifest file

```
 <!--Android 11 camera query-->
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

> Activity

```
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).also { intent ->
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().packageManager)?.also {
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE)
        }
    }
```