# Android 11 - Shareable files between apps

Tags: android, android-11, scoped-storage

We developed two android applications, one that creates a folder with multiple files *(.xml /.txt /.db)* and another one that needs to access these files. Both application needs read and write authorizations to these files.

Before Android 11, we use to store these files in the app-specific external storage *(Android/data/com...)*, the other app was able to read/write those files.

With Android 11 and enforcement of scoped storage, secondary app cannot access the primary app folder.

Is there any way of creating a "public" directory that store all shareable files ?

While searching, i found about the FileProvider component but i don't know if it will work despite scoped storage.

I'm aware of the new authorization **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**, but if i use this i'm afraid that playstore might reject my apps.

Despite all my researches, i didn't find a solution to my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "i found about the FileProvider component but i don't know if it will work despite scoped storage" -- `FileProvider` works fine.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404

Comment: you can go through this to figure out what suites you best: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Answer (score 0):

On Android 11:

Make your own directory in one of the public directories like Documents, DCIM, Pictures, Alarms and so on, and put your files there.