# Saving files in Android 11 to external storage(SDK 30)

Tags: android, file, permissions, android-external-storage, android-11

I am writing a new Application on Android 11 (SDK Version 30) and I simply cannot find an example on how to save a file to the external storage. 
 
I read their documentation and now know that they basicly ignore Manifest Permissions (`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`). They also ignore the `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the manifest.xml application tag.

In their documentation https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage they write you need to enable the `DEFAULT_SCOPED_STORAGE` and `FORCE_ENABLE_SCOPED_STORAGE` flags to enable scoped storage in your app.

Where do I have to enable those?
And when I've done that how  and when do I get the actual permission to write to the external storage? Can someone provide working code? 
 I want to save .gif, .png and .mp3 files. So I don't want to write to the gallery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can save files to the public directories on external storage.

Like Documents, Download, DCIM, Pictures and so on.

In the usual way like before version 10.

Comment: But, app doesn't recognize those files after uninstall and reinstall app.

Comment: Yes we know but that was not asked for. And.. using saf the app can.

Comment: what is saf ? and how can the app recognizes the old file that it was created before uninstall, after reinstall ?

Comment: The question is about Android 11

Comment: As I understand, you actually can use at least 4 directories: DCIM, Download, Movies, and Pictures. Each of them described as "top-level public directory" here: https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/os/Environment#DIRECTORY_DCIM

Comment: On Android 12, it's actually only "Download" and "Documents" you can write to.

Comment: No. To all public directories like i told in my post. But not all types of files go everywhere.

Comment: how can i save pictures inside Gallery - in android 10 or above means 11 or 12?

Comment: Above 10 is all that comes after ten.

Answer (score 33):

Corresponding To All Api, included Api 30, Android 11 :

```
public static File commonDocumentDirPath(String FolderName)
{
    File dir = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/" + FolderName);
    }
    else
    {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + FolderName);
    }

    // Make sure the path directory exists.
    if (!dir.exists())
    {
        // Make it, if it doesn't exit
        boolean success = dir.mkdirs();
        if (!success)
        {
            dir = null;
        }
    }
    return dir;
}
```

Now, use this `commonDocumentDirPath` for saving file.

A side note from comments, `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` with certain scopes are now working with  Api 30, Android 11. Cheers! Thanks to CommonsWare hints.

Comment: `dir.mkdirs();` mkdirs() does not throw exceptions but returns true or false. If it returns false you should let your commonDocumentDirPath function return a null. And the caller should check for null.

Comment: ??? You removed the whole mkdirs() call. Please add it again. You cannot do without.

Comment: while saving file  with getParentDirs  I have saved it.

Comment: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory & getExternalStorageDirectory both are deprecated...

Comment: @BhaveshMoradiya, yes, But now in Android 11 for the above approaches works well for all versions correspondingly. Thanks  commonsware hints.

Comment: @NoorHossain can you share the full code snippet about the camera image store? I want to capture a profile picture and store it. I tried other methods available (using manage storage permission) but while uploading on playstore it blocked my app.
Can you please help me

Comment: @VaibhavA, sorry brother I don't know about blocked. But you can test the above code for image folder or picture folder. And with runtime permission. I do not know if this solved your problem.  You can ask your question in stack overflow with your codes.

Comment: @NoorHossain I've asked a question here, please answer if you know.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67984238/7850506

Comment: It's working fine, Can you suggest to read status as well from Whatsapp? I am trying to read status from this location "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses" but not able to get it.

Comment: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated now..

Comment: @AdityaPatil, You do not know, getExternalStoragePublicDirectory came again!

Comment: @NoorHossain, you saved my day! Thanks for the code snippet

Answer (score 7):

## **Simplest Answer and Tested ( Java ) **

```
private void createFile(String title) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/html");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, Uri.parse("/Documents"));
    }
    createInvoiceActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
}

private void createInvoice(Uri uri) {
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().
                openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
        if (pfd != null) {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            fileOutputStream.write(invoice_html.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.close();
            pfd.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// You can do the assignment inside onAttach or onCreate, i.e, before the activity is displayed


    String invoice_html;
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> createInvoiceActivityResultLauncher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       invoice_html = "<h1>Just for testing received...</h1>";
       createInvoiceActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // There are no request codes
                        Uri uri = null;
                        if (result.getData() != null) {
                            uri = result.getData().getData();
                            createInvoice(uri);
                            // Perform operations on the document using its URI.
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: After a whole day, this was the solution for my PDF saving. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a perfect answer!

Comment: Using /Documents works but /Downloads not working.. You can also create  folder of your choice in Documents folder

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this method and it really worked for me
I hope I can help you. Feel free to ask me if something is not clear to you

```
   Bitmap imageBitmap;

   OutputStream outputStream ;
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
            {
                ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,"Image_"+".jpg");
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpeg");
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator+"TestFolder");
                Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,contentValues);
                try {
                    outputStream =  resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri) );
                    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
                    Objects.requireNonNull(outputStream);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Image Not Not  Saved: \n "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    
            }
```

manifest file (Add Permission)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Hi @Mark Nashat how to do for android version less than Q. By this I mean how to handle both situation?

Comment: by this the code    File filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(filePath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + context.getString(R.string.app_name) + "/");
            dir.mkdir();
            File file1 = new File(dir, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

Comment: try { outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Image Not   Saved: \n " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 try {  outputStream.flush();  outputStream.close(); } catch (IOException e) {       e.printStackTrace()      }        }

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark Nashat. Also, one last thing is how to know if a file exists in external storage in android 10+. Actually, I want to create the file if it does not exist else overwrite it. (Like you suggested answer above)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old but here is a working solution to organize your files anywhere except the root phone directory

First In Your build.gradle file, implement the SAF framework's DocumentFile class:

```
implementation 'androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.1'
```

Next Call this method which request permissions for the SAF to operate (You will only need to do this once on user install):

```
 private void requestDocumentTreePermissions() {
    // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("*Please Select A Folder For The App To Organize The Videos*")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
                    Intent intent = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();

                    String startDir = "Documents";
                    Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI");

                    String scheme = uri.toString();


                    scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/");
                    scheme += "%3A" + startDir;

                    uri = Uri.parse(scheme);
                    Uri rootUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(
                            EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY,
                            uri.toString()
                    );
                    Uri treeUri = DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(
                            EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY,
                            uri.toString()
                    );
                    uri = Uri.parse(scheme);
                    Uri treeUri2 = DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(
                            EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY,
                            uri.toString()
                    );
                    List<Uri> uriTreeList = new ArrayList<>();
                    uriTreeList.add(treeUri);
                    uriTreeList.add(treeUri2);
                    getPrimaryVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
                            .putExtra(EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, rootUri);
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                    // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
                    // the system file picker when it loads.
                    intent2.addFlags(
                            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
                                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent2.putExtra(EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, rootUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent2, 99);
                }
            })
            .setCancelable(false)
            .show();


}
```

Next Store some Persistant Permissions:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 99 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //get back the document tree URI (in this case we expect the documents root directory)
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //now we grant permanent persistant permissions to our contentResolver and we are free to open up sub directory Uris as we please until the app is uninstalled
        getSharedPreferences().edit().putString(ACCESS_FOLDER, uri.toString()).apply();
        final int takeFlags = (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
        //simply recreate the activity although you could call some function at this point
        recreate();
    }
}
```

You can call the documentFile's rename method on the correct file

```
DocumentFile df = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(MainActivity.this, uri);
df = df.findFile("CurrentName")
df.renameTo("NewName");
```

You Can also open InputStreams and OutputStreams using your content resolver because of the persistant URI permissions granted to your content resolver for that DocumentFile using the following snippet:

```
getContentResolver().openInputStream(df.getUri());
getContentResolver().openOutputStream(df.getUri());
```

InputStreams are for reading and OutputStreams are for saving

You can list files using

```
df.listFiles();
```

Or You can list out files using:

```
public static DocumentFile findFileInDirectoryMatchingName(Context mContext, Uri mUri, String name) {
    final ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
    final Uri childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(mUri,
            DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(mUri));
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = resolver.query(childrenUri, new String[]{
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID,
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE,
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED

        }, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '?%'", new String[]{name}, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            final String filename = c.getString(1);
            final String mimeType = c.getString(2);
            final Long lastModified = c.getLong(3);
            if (filename.contains(name)) {
                final String documentId = c.getString(0);
                final Uri documentUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(mUri,
                        documentId);

                return DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(mContext, documentUri);
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Which will run faster than the df.listFiles() method

Src (This is my own implementation but here is the original SF question)
[Renaming Video / Image While Targeting Android 11 (Api 30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68641037/renaming-video-image-while-targeting-android-11-api-30/68643545?noredirect=1#comment129664717_68643545)