# How to get actual file path from content path Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, uri, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to get an actual path from the content resolver path, how can I get it from the file?

My requirement is to capture an image and send it to [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper) library. I'm storing the captured image in bitmap then storing it using content resolver.

```
if (requestCode == PictureSelectorDialog.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bitmapCapturedImage = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmapCapturedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

            String contentPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(requireContext().getContentResolver(),
                    bitmapCapturedImage, "Profile_Picture_" + timeStamp, null);

            File tempImage = new File(contentPath);
            String path = tempImage.getAbsolutePath();
            imageCapture.onImageCaptured(path, false);
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67984238/capture-and-crop-image-in-android-11-r

Comment: `(Bitmap) extras.get("data");` That is only a thumbnail (120x120 or so) of a picture. No need to crop it i think.

Comment: @blackapps, our client requirement is to crop captured image. I'm trying both ways to do it, but none is working.

Comment: @blackapps 1st approach:
I saved camera captured image using bitmap and mediastore (and contentresolver). In this, I'm able to store images in all build versions. but my requirement is to get that image actual path (here media store is providing content path). the actual path is required for cropping library.

Comment: @blackapps 2nd approach: I tried using contentresolver method but in which image is not stored properly. Folder is getting created and also returned path is as expected. but problem is written image is empty.

Comment: `2nd approach: I tried using contentresolver method` ???? Contentresolver method??? Please come to the point.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67984238/7850506 2nd approach

Comment: (Bitmap) extras.get("data"); That is only a thumbnail (120x120 or so) of a picture.
yes by this we are getting captured image. but as client wants like this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/main/art/demo.gif