# How to copy file from assets to internal storage in Android 11?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, assets

The goal is to copy files from assets to internal storage and then to use it with another application (Minecraft). As I know in Android 11+ we can't create directories in internal storage so how to copy files from assets to internal storage and then use it in Minecraft?

I tried to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath` but it's deprecated.

Comment: In Android 11 you need to save files as per its type like if your file is image or video than you need to save it in "Pictures" directory, if file is audio file than need to save it in "Music" folder, if any document than need to save in "Documents or Download"

Comment: What about .mcworld files? And shoud I use "Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS" for file path to store files there?

Comment: have a look  into  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637610/saving-files-in-android-11-to-external-storagesdk-30
possible duplicate

Comment: `I know in Android 11+ we can't create directories in internal storage` Well you can. No problem. You did not try?

Comment: @AkramBaratov have you found solution to this ?

Comment: @vivekpanchal yes. You must save files only on public directories such as Downloads, Documents, etc.

Comment: @AkramBaratov please can you post your solution, I want to copy my asset's file to the downloads directory

Comment: @LouisChabert I can share access to my repo and you can get the code there. DM me please

Comment: @AkramBaratov yeah pls :)