# Can't copy file in ANDROID 11 Kotlin

Tags: android, file, kotlin, copy

I have a stupid bug in my app.

**I can copy**
*contents of a folder from a folder like `Downloads`
to `root of my app in android, data,...`*

But

**I can not** *copy contents of a folder from `root of my app in android, data,...`
to a folder like `Downloads`*

My code(that **does** work in android 11):

```
var this_dir = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Sandoghcheh")
var target_dir = File(requireActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "/backup")
copyFolder(this_dir, target_dir)
```

My code(that **does not** work in android 11):

```
var this_dir = File(requireActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "/backup")
var target_dir = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Sandoghcheh")
copyFolder(this_dir, target_dir)
```

permisions:

```
<uses-permission 
  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

<uses-permission 
 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="31" />

 <uses-permission 
 android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

fun:

```
  fun copyFolder(source: File, destination: File) {
    if (source.isDirectory) {
        if (!destination.exists()) {
            destination.mkdirs()
        }
        val files = source.list()
        for (file in files) {
            val srcFile = File(source, file)
            val destFile = File(destination, file)
            copyFolder(srcFile, destFile)
        }
    } else {
        var `in`: InputStream? = null
        var out: OutputStream? = null
        try {
            `in` = FileInputStream(source)
            out = FileOutputStream(destination)
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var length: Int
            while (`in`.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            try {
                if (`in` != null) {
                    `in`.close()
                }
            } catch (e1: IOException) {
                e1.printStackTrace()
            }
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close()
                }
            } catch (e1: IOException) {
                e1.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

reatore fun:

```
  private fun restore() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) {
        createDirectory("backup")
        val file =   File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Sandoghcheh")
        val target_dir = File(requireActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "/backup")
        copyFolder(target_dir,file )

    } else {

         val file =   File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Sandoghcheh")
        val target_dir = File(requireActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "/backup")
        copyFolder(file, target_dir)
    }

    activity?.let {
        RoomBackup()
            .customRestoreDialogTitle("یکی از بشتیبان ها را انتخاب کنید")
            .context(it)
            .database(UserDatabase.getInstance(it))
            .enableLogDebug(true)
            .backupIsEncrypted(true)
            .customEncryptPassword("Amir")
            .useExternalStorage(true)
            .apply {
                onCompleteListener { success, message ->
                    Log.d("TAG", "success: $success, message: $message")
                    if (success) restartApp(Intent(context, SplashActivity::class.java))
                }
            }
            .restore()
    }
}
```

backup fun:

```
      private fun backup() {
      context?.let {
          RoomBackup()
              .context(it)
              .database(UserDatabase.getInstance(it))
              .enableLogDebug(true)
              .backupIsEncrypted(true)
              .customEncryptPassword("Amir")
              .useExternalStorage(true)
              .maxFileCount(5)
              .apply {
                  onCompleteListener { success, message ->
                  }
              }
              .backup()
      }
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    requireActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                var this_dir = File(requireActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "/backup")
                var target_dir = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Sandoghcheh")
                copyFolder(this_dir, target_dir)
            } else {
                askPermission()
            }
            var this_dir = File(requireActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "/backup")
            var target_dir =
                File("/storage/emulated/0/Sandoghcheh")
            copyFolder(this_dir, target_dir)

        } else {
            val download_folder =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            var this_dir = File(requireActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "/backup")
            var target_dir =download_folder
            copyFolder(target_dir, this_dir)
            Log.d("TAG", "backup: $download_folder,,$this_dir")


            //                 restartApp()

    }

}
```

and last but not the least:
when I get this_dir and target_dir path it show me:

```
2022-01-21 13:41:07.938 23449-23449/com.example.holyquran D/TAG: backup: /storage/emulated/0/Download  ||||  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.holyquran/files/backup
```

Restore FUN WORKS PERFECT, IT COPIES BUT BACK UP FUN DOES NOT COPY

as I said this code is not working in **API +30**

TNX for spending time on this Q
:)

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a change in Android. I suggest you to read this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: so thanks for you comment. Can you please provide me a piece of code that can copy content of root app folder to another folder in android 11 please?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with it but I would think the link could guide you. Or maybe someone else can answer it for you

Comment: thanks in advance. but if it is a featchre in android 11, how I copy from a folder in download to root of app.

Comment: What you say does not make sense. Every app can create files in all public folders like Download and Documents. Just need normal write permissians as you used to have.

Comment: `if (!destination.exists()) {
            destination.mkdirs()
        }` Check return value of mkdirs and stop if you cannot create the directory: `if (!destination.exists()) {
            if ( !destination.mkdirs()) return;
        }` Do not try to create files in a directory that does not exist. Please tell if you could create your directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637610/saving-files-in-android-11-to-external-storagesdk-30/65640584#65640584

Comment: wait a sec i will let u know

Comment: `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Wel... if you requested that. And obtained that at runtime. Then you have access to all files and what you say is even more unbelievable.

Comment: if I delete Sandoghcheh folder, it wont create this folder, but below 30 it will

Comment: `as I said this code is not working in API +30` That is a pretty bad problem description. What happens instead? Exceptions? Errors? Crashes? Please post the relevant logcat lines.

Comment: let me provide more code

Comment: `if I delete Sandoghcheh folder, it wont create this folder, but below 30 it will ` And you did not even tell that in your post? You just said you could not copy. Sigh. And also tell \who deleted that folder. And how? Your app? We all have to guess what you do..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241274/discussion-between-amirandroiddeveloper-and-blackapps).

Comment: No chatting. Please edit your post and tell on the first lines what you did and want to do. Complete scenario. Dont let us guess.

Comment: ok I added logs and in my opinion there is no problem with copy fun. bcz it works as expected, it copies files from Sandoghcheh folder to root of my app

Comment: it can not do the oppesit thing which is coping content of a file to root of app

Comment: so just provide me code that copy contetnt of a folder, works for u and works in  android 11 TNX a million man