# Accessing external storage on Android 11 (target sdk version is 29)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an App that has to access external storage (logs, etc), and it stopped working since I updated it to Android 10. I found a workaround to set

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

and it works fine on Android 10 now, but not on Android 11. I heard that this should still work on Android 11 if my app is targeting android 10 (SDK 29), so in my case, it should work. But it doesn't, and I still get deployment failed, permission denied

Comment: Yes indeed that does not work there.

Comment: @yeetyeet From [Manage device storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#manage-device-storage), Starting in Android 11, apps that use the scoped storage model can access only their own app-specific cache files.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Actually it works if I run it in Relese mode, debug is still not working..

Comment: In android 11,you should request the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: Adding MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest doent seem to work. Or did you have any other way in mind?

Comment: @yeetyeet You said that it works on Release mode, just not work on Debug mode? It is strange.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT yes, exactly. It works on Debug without fast deployment as well, haha

Comment: @yeetyeet You mean that you have solved your problem now?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404