# Access app specific external storage from Adb on Android 11 and higher

Tags: java, android, adb

I have an Android app that communicates some information to a WPF app by creating a file in app-specific external storage dir https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#external. WPF app pulls this file over Adb and processes it.

This is working fine for most devices except for Samsung S21 (API Level 30), where I keep getting this error:
*Failed to pull '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/...'. open failed: Permission denied*

What is the reason for this behavior? and how can I access the said file on S21?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404