# Which is Best Special Folder to use for compatibility with Scoped Storage of Android 11 in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, scoped-storage

According to Android 11 Documentation, the app-specific data should be stored in app specific storage. This is the location where the app has full access to read/write/manage.
In Xamarin.Forms which Special Folder does it correspond to : Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
or Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments or some other Folder altogether?

Comment: What you ask for has no connection with the scoped storage. That is something very different.

Comment: @Ivan Ičin, Asking which directory to use for scoped storage has everything to do with scoped storage

Comment: @blackapps "According to Android 11 Documentation, the app-specific data should be stored in app specific storage." This is the question it is entirely valid, but it has nothing with scoped storage. Do you know what is scoped storage at all?

Comment: Heard about it. Its pretty much using app specific storage only. It brings nothing new. Its no feature. Its only a restriction.

Comment: @blackapps why do you comment if your knowledge is at the level of 'heard of it'?

Comment: Well it looked to me that you had not heard of it at all. Or certainly did not understood the thing.

Comment: With scoped storage enabled, no permissions are required to access files created by your own application (whether the files are created in internal storage or external storage).

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404