# Android 11 SQLite with Scoped Storage

Tags: sqlite, uri, android-11, scoped-storage

It doesn't seem like I can access and load a sqlite file anywhere outside of the apps "files" folder (i.e. Andorid/Data/my.app/files). Am I missing something? It doesn't seem like SQLite can use a Uri to load a database unless that data is copied to a temp location or something. Is there nowhere my app can use the normal file system other than the apps location?

Thanks.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404

Comment: @ThoriyaPrahalad That was a temporary workaround back then. It doesn't work anymore,  seems like they haven't thought everything through before making drastic changes, as always.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your file for instance in the Documents directory.

Comment: What if the file is not created by our app in the first place?

Comment: In the first place that was not your question.