# How to open a file from shared storage using the NDK in Android 11

Tags: android, android-ndk

The permissions for accessing shared storage (`/storage/emulated/0`) are getting really really complicated and changing all the time. As I understand it when targeting Android 11 there is no way to opt out of scoped storage, which means you literally can't ever do `fopen("/storage/emulated/0/foo.dat");`. Apparently the preferred way to open a file will be with the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` but this just returns a `content://` URI, which I can't read using the NDK. I'm also unsure if you get to use that URI forever.

How are NDK libraries meant to access files in `/storage/emulated/0` on Android 11?

Comment: fopen("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/foo.dat");.

Comment: @blackapps: That won't work when targeting Android 11 as far as I can tell.

Comment: Apparently you dit not even try to create a file in that way.

Comment: No because I read the documentation saying it will not work. Did you try it?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think you have misread my question and your app is probably running on Android 11 but targets an earlier version.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9917404

Answer (score 3):

Aha, it seems they have moved the permission to read/write all files to [`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files). It's one of those permissions that users have to grant in settings, and there's an intent (`ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`) to take people directly there.

However they probably won't let you upload an app to the play store with this permission unless it's a file manager or similar, and you currently can't use it at all.

> If your app includes a use case that's similar to the following examples, it's likely to be allowed to request the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission:
>
> - File managers
> - Backup and restore
> - Anti-virus apps
> - Document management apps
>
> Due to COVID-19 related considerations, apps that target Android 11 (API level 30) or higher and need the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission cannot be uploaded to Google Play until early 2021.

I should also note that there seems to be [an exception for opening *media files*](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#direct-file-paths) only - i.e. files indexed by Android's media scanner.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 11 devices:

All apps can write files in all the public directories like Dowload, Documents, DCIM, Pictures and so on.

If not in the directory itself then in a subdirectory of it which you create first.

For DCIM and Pictures only files with extension like .jpg,  .png and .webp are accepted.

More public directories only accept certain extensions.

Comment: Do you have an actual reference for that? It directly contradicts what it says [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage): `apps that target Android 10 (API level 29) and higher are given scoped access into external storage, or scoped storage, by default. Such apps have access only to the app-specific directory on external storage, as well as specific types of media that the app has created.`

Comment: I'm not going to spend hours setting up code for something that *the documentation says will not work and you have not provided any evidence for*. As I said in my answer, media files are given a special exception and I suspect you are getting confused by that.

Comment: Pretty strange that changing fopen("/storage/emulated/0/foo.dat"); to fopen("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/foo.dat"); would cost you hours. And im not confused. For the rest i just gave an answer to your question. Strange you want more. Just try and confirm. After that we can talk.

Comment: I haven't written the code yet. That's why it would take several hours to verify that your solution - that you have provided no evidence for and contradicts the documentation - actually works.

Comment: How would you like me to provide evidence? What do you have in mind? If you think it is not true what i said then try it and come back telling that it did not work. But that will not happen as it will work.

Comment: Your code will do. Well if you open in creating mode. (cannot see if you do). You cannot just try to read a file created by another app or copied to that directory by other means.

Comment: "You cannot just try to read a file created by another app or copied to that directory by other means." Glad you finally agree!

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that public Download directory is still writable under Android.