# How do I compress image in android studio(JAVA) and store it in device specific folder

Tags: java, android, deprecated, image-resizing, image-compression

I am making an app for image compression And I am new to Android development....So my problem is as we have some issue with accessing External storage in JAVA......I have Tried

```
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
```

```java
compressedImage = new Compressor(this)
    .setMaxWidth(640)
    .setMaxHeight(480)
    .setQuality(75)
    .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP)
    .setDestinationDirectoryPath(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
        ).getAbsolutePath()
    )
    .compressToFile(actualImage);
```

Okayy...so can I use WEBP_LOSSLESS instead of WEBP for Android API 30?
and The main issue is how do I set the destination for storing in Specific Folder?

Comment: I want to save compressed image in device as we can't use ExternalStorage public library in API 30 so how do I save it at particular directory

Answer (score 1):

The red deprecation box of [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) lists alternatives:

> Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage
> by migrating to alternatives such as
> [`Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)),
> [`MediaStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore),
> or
> [`Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).

[`Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat#WEBP) also contains a deprecation notice:

> This field was deprecated in API level 30. in favor of the more
> explicit
> [`CompressFormat#WEBP_LOSSY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat#WEBP_LOSSY)
> and
> [`CompressFormat#WEBP_LOSSLESS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat#WEBP_LOSSLESS).

---

For example, something like this should work:

```
Context ctx = this;
File storeFolder = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

compressedImage = new Compressor(this)
    .setMaxWidth(640)
    .setMaxHeight(480)
    .setQuality(75)
    .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP_LOSSLESS)
    .setDestinationDirectoryPath(
        storeFolder.getAbsolutePath()
    )
    .compressToFile(actualImage);
```

Comment: I am new here Can you provide code for storeFolder?

Comment: @AVITHAKUR I'm not sure I follow. Could you be more specific?

Comment: yess...okay so basically  I am making an android app for image compression and I wanted to use the zelory compressor as I am new to android development I was not sure how to use this compressor with API 29 & 30...But I have tried different approach as mentioned below...

Comment: okay...I wanna post the code that I tried and its working but its too long for the comment...so should  I post it as Question or what?

Comment: @AVITHAKUR If you have any new information to add to your question, simply [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66534787/edit) it.