# How to access folder in android11 programitically?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11

I want to write a code in kotlin (android11) that opens the internal storage directory so that I can select a pdf file from that directory. But due to restrictions, I can't do this.

Please suggest to me a way to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the same way as before. You did not try  i supose. And for selecting a file you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782648/android-11-scoped-storage-permissions

Answer (score -1):

```
requestLegacyExternalStorage
```

is always false in API 30 if

```
    preserveLegacyExternalStorage
```

is set then requestLegacyExternalStorage is true (this is a pure migration case and this state won't be preserved should the user uninstall/reinstall the app).

Comment: Can u please share some sample code to do this.

Comment: add this line in the application tag in the manifest file :
preserveLegacyExternalStorage=true