# Android 11 all pdf files access fails

Tags: android, file, android-11

I'm targeting now android 11 and all of us know about [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage),

my case is that I need to access all pdfs files on the phone it's working for any android less than android 11.

I've tried to grant permission `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but, I don't know why it fails with me, I'm able to read jpg patter files but, the pdf files I can't.

this is my code:

```
public ArrayList<PdfData> Search_Dir(File dir) {

        String pdfPattern = ".pdf";
        File[] FileList = dir.listFiles();

        if (FileList != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < FileList.length; i++) {
                File file = FileList[i];

                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    Search_Dir(file);
                } else {
                    if (file.getName().endsWith(pdfPattern)) {
                        Log.v("fileNameIs ", " " + i + file.getName());
                        String file_size = Formatter.formatShortFileSize(getApplicationContext(), file.length());
                        PdfData pdfData = new PdfData();
                        pdfData.setFile(file);
                        pdfData.setFileName(file.getName());
                        pdfData.setFileSize(file_size);
                        pdfDataList.add(pdfData);

                        Log.v("fileSize is : ", ": " + file_size);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return pdfDataList;
}
```

i call the method like that

**`list = Search_Dir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());`**

Comment: @Zain can you help with this?

Comment: This permission has some restrictions please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782648/android-11-scoped-storage-permissions)

Comment: ya, i did and know but, i need a way to read all pdfs files, is there any solution?

Comment: It is pretty unclear where Searche_Dir would search.

Comment: `tried to grant permission` Ahh you cannot grant that permission. Only request. And then the user should allow it in the settings for your app.

Comment: @blackapps Searche_Dir  will search in all file i'm calling `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: it's fails without showing the popup for allow

Comment: Popup? Which popup? Which allow?

Comment: On an Android 11 device an app will only see its own pdf files.

Comment: popup for permission allow using permissions, a second point not true as there are some apps like virus scanning have access t all phones docs