# How to pick image from shared storage in android 11 device?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11, android-update-sdk

I used this library https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker and I got a warning from the android play console, team We've detected that your app contains the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag in the manifest file of 1 or more of your app bundles or APKs. Developers with apps on devices running Android 11+ must use Scoped Storage to give users better access control over their device storage. To release your app on Android 11 or newer after May 5th, you must either:

Comment: Hey @blackapps my question is related to android permission to pick an image from the gallery for all android version till android 11 But I don't know what is the correct way to implement  or fix my problem

Comment: To pick an image from 'the gallery' you do not need any permission or flags to begin with. Not for any Android version.  So what is your problem?

Comment: @blackapps without gallery if we are picking image from storage that time we need permission right

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are doing while 'picking an image from storage'. And if you change the subject then adapt your text too as the gallery is still there. Start with writing a to the point post.

Comment: @blackapps I need little bit help for you .

Comment: I used this library https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker and I got a warning form the android play console, team We've detected that your app contains the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag in the manifest file of 1 or more of your app bundles or APKs.

Developers with apps on devices running Android 11+ must use Scoped Storage to give users better access control over their device storage. To release your app on Android 11 or newer after May 5th, you must either:

Comment: Well then make a different subject and start your post with your last comment.

Comment: And why dont you use ACTION_GET_CONTENT or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to pick images? No permissions or flags needed.

Comment: Okay, I will try both intents. Have you used for pick image using these intents ?@blackapps Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

- Before **Android 10**, we have a concept of Shared Storage. Every
  application in the device has some private storage in the internal memory and you can find this in the **android/data/your_package_name
  directory**. Apart from this internal storage, the rest of the
  storage is called the Shared Storage i.e. every application with the
  storage permission can access this part of the memory. This includes
  media collections and other files of different applications. But the
  problem is that the application having the storage permission doesn't
  require access to all of these files. All they want is to perform
  some small operation over some small part of the memory and that's
  it. For example, some application just needs to select a user image
  to upload it as the profile picture and nothing else. So, why provide
  them with full access to that Shared Storage?
- Also, the second problem is that when the application is having such
  a wide writing capability on the storage then the files generated by
  the application gets scattered and when the user uninstalls the
  application then the files generated by the application remains in
  the storage only and are not deleted and takes a lot of space.
- So, we need some kind of mechanism, with the help of which the apps
  can get the specific access they need without getting such a broad
  reading and writing power that they don't actually need. This can be
  done with the help of **Scoped Storage**.

Note:- **From Android 11 onwards googles forces to used Scope Storage** Check This [Link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

Comment: Hey, Krishna have you used READ and WRITE permission in android 11?

Comment: Yes, I used. you can check this it will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/9523118

Comment: Hey I saw that your answer But before 5th May 2021 you added MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission in code

Comment: I guess this permission will be effective after may 5th

Comment: And we must also mention what permission you are using for in play store

Answer (score -1):

```
<queries>
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
</intent>
```

Don't forget to put queries tag in your manifest file.
use this code in your manifest file...