# java.io.IOException: No such device Error in Android 11

Tags: java, android, android-11, android-storage

```
FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
```

src path is --> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20210630_182546.jpg

this is destination folder --> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tp.qa/files/temp

destination image name --> /gallery1625059659.jpg

Is there some problem in copying file from the above source?

Comment: `....No such device .... Which device?

Comment: This is the error that was shown in the logs

Comment: The problem here is probably `source`.. Not sure how you got that, but it's best to use the `Uri` returned from `MediaStore` to copy the file to your applications directory.

Answer (score 1):

In android 11 directly accessing storage is not Allowed. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) how to use scoped permission in Android 11. You can try out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67167632/8332511). In my case this worked.

Comment: So are you saying there is no way to copy a file from shared storage to app's folder??