# List of files incomplete when using File.listfiles() on Android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app running on Android 11 where I am trying to list the contents of the Download directory.

At first try I was getting just the folder names. Then I added

```
requestPermissions( EXTERNAL_PERMS, EXTERNAL_REQUEST);
```

Now I am getting .mp3, and .jpg files listed but not other like .pdf

Any idea how to fix this?

I have been reading and trying all the permission requests.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And the code for gettting the files:

```
requestPermissions(EXTERNAL_PERMS, EXTERNAL_REQUEST);
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File files[] = path.listFiles();
```

Thank you

Comment: Android 11 puts limitations on grabbing files that are not owned by your app.

Comment: Is there any way to get around it?

Comment: Yes with for instance  .MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by " with for instance .MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: That will give you all files access.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the answer from this post and now I can get access to all files.

[Android 11 Scoped storage permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782648/android-11-scoped-storage-permissions)

I understand that the answer provided here is most likely not accepted in the PlayStore but for me that is ok.