# choose file with intent android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to select a file, but in Android 11 I either do not have access to the files and either the downloaded file is empty

[These are my codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3oC5.jpg)

Comment: Please put code as text in a code block in your post.

Comment: To add to blackapps' comment, do not simply drop the code into the post; [code samples](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be minimal, complete and representative. See: "[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/90527)", "[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527)" and the [help] (especially "[ask]").

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is the similar Question that you are asking for scoped storage permissions with handling of the data selected by user.
You can use this question for reference.

[Android 11 Scoped storage permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782648/android-11-scoped-storage-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

Try this library [**AndroidFilePicker**](https://github.com/rosuH/AndroidFilePicker). It supports Android 11.