# With Android 11, how to write file to SDCard in HAL Layer?

Tags: android

I want to write test file to SDCard with Android 11, I close selinux with "adb shell setenforce 0", but fopen() will give errno 13 error,how to fix it？ Thanks.

Comment: Read about "Storage Scope" of Android 11, then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782648/android-11-scoped-storage-permissions

Comment: But I want to write to sdcard in hal layer, not in app

Answer (score 0):

With selinux as permissive, you also need to check if the HAL executable has appropriate permissions to be able to create a file in the destination path. Check username and group name for HAL executable and the destination path.

For example: if HAL executable has 'system' user, /data/<file-name.extn> can be used as destination which has both user and group as 'system'.