# No permissions found in manifest for: []9 in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, permissions, request, handler

I got the following warning on the console although the app works fine. I wonder what is the permission for `[]9`? The following is what I have in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.blueedgez.finger_maestro">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

The following is the code snippet that I use to request permissions for microphone and photos.

```
checkPermission() async{
    await isMicOK();
    await isPhotoOK();
    if(!permA[0])  {
      await requestMicPermission().then((_) async{
        if( !permA[0] && ! await isPermDeny(0) && Platform.isAndroid){
          await requestMicPermission().then((_){});
        }
      });
    }
    if(!permA[1])  {

      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        final androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
        sdkVersion=androidInfo.version.sdkInt;
        if (androidInfo.version.sdkInt <= 32) {
          /// use [Permissions.storage.status]
          await requestStoragePermission().then((_) async {
            if (!permA[1] && !await isPermDeny(2)) {
              await requestStoragePermission().then((_) {});
            }
          });
        } else {
          /// use [Permissions.photos.status]
          await requestPhotoPermission().then((_) async {
            if (!permA[1] && !await isPermDeny(1)) {
              await requestPhotoPermission().then((_) {});
            }
          });
        }
      }
      else {
        await requestPhotoPermission().then((_) async {
          if (!permA[1] && !await isPermDeny(1)) {
            await requestPhotoPermission().then((_) {});
          }
        });
      }
    }
    if( ! permA[0] || ! permA[1]) {
      showPermissionDialog(context);
    }
  }
```

The app works as expected but I just don't know what else needs to be in `Android`Manifest.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74826687/how-to-solve-no-permissions-found-in-manifest-for-9-in-flutter

Comment: Yes, I saw that thread before I posted my question. I did the same implementation by granting storage or photo depending on SDK version but the warning still shows although the app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in my code. I did check the SDK version to either requesting for storage or photo permission when I request permissions but I didn't check the SDK version when I check the permission That's why I get the warning. The warning is gone after I implement the SDK checking.